# Xamarin forms UWP Silent printing

Tags: c#, xamarin, service, printing, uwp

I have the need to print a html document from a UWP Xamarin forms app with out the print confirmation dialog being shown to the user.
I have looked into Using full trust but this seems to have been removed.
Setting

```
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Reports rescap is invalid.

I have also tried using a service to print with no luck.
Using InternetExplorer or WebBrowser to format and print works fine from a windows forms app but running in a service will ether never return from navigating to the document or from the command to print.

```
void PrintOnStaThread(string htmlPath)
{
    const short PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION = 2;
    const int OLECMDID_PRINT = 6;
    const int OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2;
    using (var browser = new WebBrowser())
    {
        DebugLog.WriteLog("Control WebBrowser created");
        browser.Navigate(htmlPath);
        while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            DebugLog.WriteLog("DoEvents loop");
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        DebugLog.WriteLog("DoEvents loop finished");
        dynamic ie = browser.ActiveXInstance;
        ie.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION);
        DebugLog.WriteLog("DoEvents loop finished end of method");
    }
}
```

or

```
public void Print(string htmlFilename)
{
    documentLoaded = false;
    documentPrinted = false;
    DebugLog.WriteLog("Pre new InternetExplorer()");
    InternetExplorer ie = new  InternetExplorerClass();
    ie.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(ie_DocumentComplete);
    ie.PrintTemplateTeardown += new DWebBrowserEvents2_PrintTemplateTeardownEventHandler(ie_PrintTemplateTeardown);

    object missing = Missing.Value;
    DebugLog.WriteLog("Pre navigate");
    ie.Navigate(htmlFilename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    while (!documentLoaded && ie.QueryStatusWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT) != OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    DebugLog.WriteLog("Doc loaded");
    ie.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, ref missing, ref missing);
    DebugLog.WriteLog("Printing");
    while (!documentPrinted)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        DebugLog.WriteLog("Printing loop");
    }
    DebugLog.WriteLog("Printed");
    ie.DocumentComplete -= ie_DocumentComplete;
    ie.PrintTemplateTeardown -= ie_PrintTemplateTeardown;
    ie.Quit();
}
```

I have tried many different variants of these approaches all with the same result.

Implementing code that people have used to the past (dated around 2016) seems to no longer work so I am assuming that this has been restricted by Microsoft.
Does anyone know away to achieve what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with a full trust component. Silent printing is a known gap in the UWP context, and it currently requires a full trust component. There is a [UserVoice entry to allow direct printing](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/6185763-allow-direct-printing-without-modern-ui-print-dial) being explored.

The problem you're having with the full trust capability is that you need to define the rescap prefix in your manifest as shown in the [Restricted Capabilities section of the App capability declarations document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities) .

> To declare a restricted capability, modify your app package manifest source file (Package.appxmanifest). Add the xmlns:rescap XML namespace declaration, and use the rescap prefix when you declare your restricted capability. For example, here's how to declare the appCaptureSettings capability.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
    ...
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="... rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="appCaptureSettings"/>
</Capabilities>
</Package>
```

I don't suspect that the code you looked at from 2016 didn't work in a UWP context then either. I don't know specifically what you're running into when printing from a service: doing so is significantly more complicated than it sounds both in setting up the service correctly to be able to print and in making sure that you use printing API that are designed for use in a service (my best guess is that the IE controls you're using aren't). Printing from a full trust component in your app will be much easier and more direct. You can write that component in WinForms if that's the framework you're most familiar with.